# Adding core-ui disabled attribute conditional to fieldset tag inside form component

Tags: reactjs, jsx, core-ui

I'm working with a react spring-boot codebase that uses core-ui for frontend I am needing to disable all form fields if form is in use. I have added an isLocked attribute to the backend table and can get the value on the page I need to disable the fields on. I have tried severals approaches but none seem to work.

I've tried

```
<fieldset {isDisabled} >
```

but get error
    Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

```
<fieldset {data.isLocked ? 'disabled' : null} >
```

but also throws similar error

I have to use

```
<fieldset disabled >
```

because core-ui fieldset disabled does not work any other way see link
https://coreui.io/docs/components/forms/#disabled-forms

If anybody has any suggestions please advise

I've tried like this but get error

```
{ data.isLocked && <fieldset disabled  >}

  Line 2320:  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?

  2318 |                               </Content>
  2319 |                               </fieldset>
> 2320 |                           </Form>
       |                           ^
  2321 |                       </div>
```

Comment: You probably meant `<fieldset disabled={isDisabled} >`. Also can you share some of your render code, it seems JSX error is thrown over there

Comment: using "<fieldset disabled={isDisabled} >" causes the form to always be disabled no matter if its true or false

Comment: that depends on your `isDisabled` value what it holds and how it is calculated

Comment: I think its an issue with core-ui that I have to use "<fieldset disabled >" I've tested in console and  "<fieldset disabled="false" >" still disables form only works if disabled is present or not present

Comment: `disabled` prop itself disables the HTML element, you dont pass `false` to it rather React takes care of it, thus I said it depends on what it holds and how it is calculated. Share relevant code in order to get more insight so that we can help you out better

Comment: "isDisabled" console.logs out "disabled"

Comment: so its a string `"disabled"` which is always going to be truthy thus its disabled. you need something like: `<fieldset disabled={isDisabled === "disabled" ? true : false} >`

Comment: will give that a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are really using to determine disabled part but based on your question you need to use:

Using `isDisabled` value you would do something like below:

```
<fieldset disabled={isDisabled === "disabled" ? true : false} >
```

OR, using `data.isLocked`

```
<Form>
  <fieldset disabled={data.isLocked ? true : false} >
    ...
  </fieldset>
</Form>
```

Comment: thank you this worked "<fieldset disabled={data.isLocked === 1 ? true : false}>" appreciate it will research more into this